# omniauth.auth for Facebook not returning full hash and not able to successfully login with facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I'm working on the facebook clone project from http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/final-project.

I'm stuck with the omniauth-facebook portion, and I'm not able to successfully login with facebook. I think the problem might be due to the request.env["omniauth.auth"]. When I try to raise request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml. I get the following incomplete hash. It's missing a lot of information such as first_name, last_name, gender, etc.

```
--- !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
provider: facebook
uid: &#39;10206926404981253&#39;
info: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash
  name: Thomas Pan
  image: http://graph.facebook.com/10206926404981253/picture
credentials: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
  token: <token>
  expires_at: 1442277104
  expires: true
extra: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
  raw_info: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
    name: Thomas Pan
    id: <id>
```

** Replaced some info with <> for security.

I'm using this along with devise as well.

Everything else seems to be set up correctly as I've followed the instructions here for devise and omniauth-facebook. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

user.rb

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
   :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
   :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
    user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
    user.gender = auth.extra.raw.gender
  end  
end
```

devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FB_APP_ID'], ENV['FB_APP_SECRET']
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations", :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth-callbacks" }
```

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
def facebook
  raise request.env['omniauth.auth'].to_yaml
  end
end
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Version info:
Rails 4.2.1
Ruby 2.0.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `devise.rb`:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FB_APP_ID'], ENV['FB_APP_SECRET'], scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name,first_name,last_name,gender'
```

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thank you! I can't believe it was that simple. I'm still a little confused though. From every guide that I've seen, the full hash info seems to display by default without any a scope. This answer definitely worked, but is there a reason why it seems like every other code I've seen omits this yet still gets the full hash?

Comment: Oh man! You saved my day! Was it that easy? Thomas I agree with you- Every guide or stack overflow guide or questions totally overlook this! Thank you  oyakata.

Answer (score 1):

**Create a OmniauthCallbacksController and Add the following code**

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def all
    p env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      # flash[:alert] = "You have to confirm your account before continuing."
      sign_in_and_redirect(user)
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

    def failure
      #handle you logic here..
      #and delegate to super.
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end


  alias_method :facebook, :all
end
```

In your config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks" }
```

**Create a Authorization model**

```
rails g model Authorization
```

**In migration add following code**

```
class CreateAuthorizations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :authorizations do |t|
      t.string :provider
      t.string :uid
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :token
      t.string :secret
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**then**

```
rake db:migrate
```

**In your models/authorization.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**In your models/user.rb**

```
has_many :authorizations

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  authorization = Authorization.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid.to_s).first_or_initialize
  authorization.token = auth.credentials.token
  if authorization.user.blank?
    user = User.where('email = ?', auth["info"]["email"]).first
    if user.blank?
     user = User.new
     user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,10]
     user.email = auth.info.email
     user.save
    end
   authorization.user_id = user.id       
  end
  authorization.save
  authorization.user
end
```

Hope this will help you.